# Newbie trying to fix the margins

Tags: margins

I have a document I created with no issues using a template, but there is one part which is still mystery to me. I would like to set the margins so that there is equal distance to horizontal edges on both sides.

I saw in the template there are two commands which dictate the horizontal settings, and I changed the numbers in them to get margins to my liking. Yet, every time I change these values the values shift to right or left. I would like the entire text to be centered on an A4 paper.

```
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2.75cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{5.5cm}
```

I have tried and these two lines above set the margins. How do I include a new command or change the definitions so that I can set the text to be always centered?

In the LaTeX document, there is a folder named "style", in it there are two files: `head.tex` and `header.tex`, and in the main folder there is `main.tex`.

**`main.tex:`**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\input{style/head.tex}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\assignmentnumber}{1} % replace X with the lab session number
\newcommand{\coursename}{coursename}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut} 
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\input{style/header.tex}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\begin{equation}
    a= b+c
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**`style/head.tex`**

```
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2.75cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{5.5cm}

\addtolength{\textheight}{5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-3.50cm}

\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Package to generate dummy text
\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Use UTF-8 encoding
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb} % Mathematical typesetting
\usepackage{float} % Improved interface for floating objects
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF

\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx, multicol} % Enhanced support for graphics
\usepackage{xcolor} % Driver-independent color extensions
\usepackage{pseudocode} % Environment for specifying algorithms in a natural way
\usepackage[mmddyy]{datetime} % Uses YEAR-MONTH-DAY format for dates

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Custom footer text
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Custom footer text
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Custom footer text
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\marginpar{\scriptsize \textcolor{red}{#1}}} % Enables comments in red on margin

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
```

**`style/header.tex`**

```
\fancyhead[C]{}
%\hrule \medskip
\begin{minipage}{0.295\textwidth} 
\raggedright
%\footnotesize
\large
name\hfill
%\youremail
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
\centering 
\large 
\textbf{central title \assignmentnumber}
\normalsize 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.295\textwidth} 
\raggedleft
\coursename
%\today\hfill\\
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-0.5em}
{\hrule height 0.0200cm}
%\medskip\hrule
\hrule
%\bigskip
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's simpler to change the general layout with package `geometry`. This being said, the traditional rules of typography  say that the inner margin has to be smaller than the outer margin, for the very good reason that, when you read a book, you see two inner margins side by side – the inner margin of the left page and the inner margin of the right page. Furthermore, one has to take into account the binding offset.

Comment: In a `twoside` document the margins are different in recto and verso pages but they are constant in a `oneside` document.